# workspace.fs is not available in vscode API to read the file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanted to use vscode.workspace api to deal with file operations instead of node fs module as shown in the following [Git Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/vscode-api-tests/src/singlefolder-tests/workspace.fs.test.ts). But i am not able to access fs inside workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run `npm install @types/vscode` to ensure you have the latest types for vscode. This resolved our problem when trying to use `vscode.workspace.fs`.